# Starting intent causes ClassCastException

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've successfully setup an ActionBar using ActionBarSherlock and it sets intents to start when I select an option on it.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_collection:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Collection.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_wishlist:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Wishlist.class));
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The problem is that when this intent is supposed to start I get this error:

```
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage.thing/com.mypackage.thing.Wishlist}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mypackage.thing.Wishlist
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mypackage.thing.Wishlist
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
09-10 20:30:15.496: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  ... 11 more
```

Is something wrong with the class that's supposed to initiate or in the xml files? i'm using the support package along with ActionBarSherlock. I've tried checking the manifest and layouts but nothing seems to be wrong there. Also I'm very new to fragments so not sure if thats set up correctly. The class that's supposed to start has:

```
   ...
   import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;
   import com.mypackage.thing.contentprovider.DatabaseProvider;
   import com.mypackage.thing.database.WishlistTable;

   public class Wishlist extends SherlockListFragment
                implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

   ...

   //Inflate ListFragment view
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.wishlist, container, false);
   }

   ...
```

The class is then set up to use a cursorLoader and a provider/cursorAdapter to populate a list from SQLite.

Comment: `WishList` is a fragment not an activity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WishList` class extends `SherlockListFragment`. This is not an `Activity` class (see [`ListFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html).

To put this in an `Activity`, you must create a new [`FragmentActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) (or rather, `SherlockFragmentActivity`) that hosts this fragment. [This documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) may help you.

Comment: Thanks! Fragments seem useful but haven't used them before.

Comment: They're very useful... ever since Android 3.x, they've become the bread and butter of layouts. Use them lots, learn them well! :)